# TreeView in asp.net : How to insert two column in child nodes in treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am developing one project. There I want to add 2 columns in child nodes of treeview. I am using C#.NET. How can I get it?

Sorry for my English.

I  want to do like following

```
     + Parent Node
         - Child Node [Text] [Button]  
         - Child Node [Text1] [Button1]
         - Child Node [Text2] [Button2]
```

Can I do like above?

Thanks 
RedDevils

Comment: What exactly you can not do? Did you tried to create new TreeNode and add to the ChildNodes of Root/an other node of TreeView control?

Comment: you question is not in proper way to ask, no one understand your question easily. make it simple and easy to understood by any one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802724/how-to-create-a-multicolumn-treeview-like-this-in-c-sharp-winforms-app/9802753#9802753 Check this link..problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

`DataSet dtTree = ObjUser.GetAllClientGroupandList();`

```
         TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();

         if (dtTree != null)   
        {
            // Create DataRelation.................  
            DataRelation rel = new DataRelation("ClientCategory", dtTree.Tables[0].Columns["TPAClientGroupId"],
            dtTree.Tables[1].Columns["TPAClientGroupId"], false);
            rel.Nested = true;

            dtTree.Relations.Add(rel);
             // Set the Attribute here .........................
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dtTree.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
            }
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dtTree.Tables[1].Columns)
            {
                dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
            }

           // xml decleartion ......................................
            XmlDataSource xmlD = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource();


            xmlD.ID = "XmlDataSource1";
            // Call GetXml and assign to xml data source. 
            XmlDataSource1.Data = dtTree.GetXml();


        }
```

Comment: I can only do with xml? can you show me with datatable and how to insert 2 columns per one note?