# How to create a MultiColumn treeview like this in C# Winforms app?

Tags: c#, treeview

```
Parent         Col1    Col2    Col3  
|
|____ Child    Data1   Data2  Data3
|
|____ Child2   Data1    Data2  Data3
```

Comment: what you've tried to do? what doesn't work? try google first

Comment: I need to create a Treeview with multiple columns in csharp but i dont know how to do that ?

Comment: now the graphics looks a lot better ;)

Comment: thanks .. pls help me to do this task i am a fresher to csharp

Comment: Component vendors have this kind of component in their catalog.  They call it "TreeList".

Comment: Related  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502627/windows-forms-treeview-control-with-multiple-colums

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) library, is very powerful and pretty easy to use.

Here's a full example:

1) compile the ObjectListView source code to get a `ObjectListView.dll`
2) create a new Windows Forms Application and add the `ObjectListView.dll` as reference
3) Open the Form1.cs code and copy the following code inside:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // embedded class
    class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Column1 { get; private set; }
        public string Column2 { get; private set; }
        public string Column3 { get; private set; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; private set; }
        public Node(string name, string col1, string col2, string col3)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Column1 = col1;
            this.Column2 = col2;
            this.Column3 = col3;
            this.Children = new List<Node>();
        }
    }

    // private fields
    private List<Node> data;
    private BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView treeListView;

    // constructor
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddTree();
        InitializeData();
        FillTree();
    }

    // private methods
    private void FillTree()
    {
        // set the delegate that the tree uses to know if a node is expandable
        this.treeListView.CanExpandGetter = x => (x as Node).Children.Count > 0;
        // set the delegate that the tree uses to know the children of a node
        this.treeListView.ChildrenGetter = x => (x as Node).Children;

        // create the tree columns and set the delegates to print the desired object proerty
        var nameCol = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("Name", "Name");
        nameCol.AspectGetter = x => (x as Node).Name;

        var col1 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("Column1", "Column1");
        col1.AspectGetter = x => (x as Node).Column1;

        var col2 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("Column2", "Column2");
        col2.AspectGetter = x => (x as Node).Column2;

        var col3 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("Column3", "Column3");
        col3.AspectGetter = x => (x as Node).Column3;

        // add the columns to the tree
        this.treeListView.Columns.Add(nameCol);
        this.treeListView.Columns.Add(col1);
        this.treeListView.Columns.Add(col2);
        this.treeListView.Columns.Add(col3);

        // set the tree roots
        this.treeListView.Roots = data;
    }

    private void InitializeData()
    {
        // create fake nodes
        var parent1 = new Node("PARENT1", "-", "-", "-");
        parent1.Children.Add(new Node("CHILD_1_1", "A", "X", "1"));
        parent1.Children.Add(new Node("CHILD_1_2", "A", "Y", "2"));
        parent1.Children.Add(new Node("CHILD_1_3", "A", "Z", "3"));

        var parent2 = new Node("PARENT2", "-", "-", "-");
        parent2.Children.Add(new Node("CHILD_2_1", "B", "W", "7"));
        parent2.Children.Add(new Node("CHILD_2_2", "B", "Z", "8"));
        parent2.Children.Add(new Node("CHILD_2_3", "B", "J", "9"));

        var parent3 = new Node("PARENT3", "-", "-", "-");
        parent3.Children.Add(new Node("CHILD_3_1", "C", "R", "10"));
        parent3.Children.Add(new Node("CHILD_3_2", "C", "T", "12"));
        parent3.Children.Add(new Node("CHILD_3_3", "C", "H", "14"));

        data = new List<Node> { parent1, parent2, parent3 };
    }

    private void AddTree()
    {
        treeListView = new BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView();
        treeListView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(treeListView);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sir i have to create it through Xml data.Its so confusing can u help me ?

Comment: sir please mail me this aravindsrinivas23@gmail.com ..thanks for ur help..

Comment: sir what is BrightIdeasSoftware ... It shows errror..i cant understand this

Comment: @user1283106: I think you should be able to reproduce my result just following my instructions. If you can't even do this I hardly think you can go any further. So, if you have doubts don't hesitate to ask, but please try to create this project by yourself :)

Comment: @user1283106: as I said in the instruction, you must compile the ObjectListView (download the source from the link I posted) and once you got the `ObjectListView.dll` add a reference to it in your project. BrightIdeasSoftware is the namespace defined inside that dll.

Comment: Sir i tried it but its not comming thats why asked u ..

Comment: It shows error in BrightIdeasSoftware i added that dll also..

Comment: @user1283106: Here's the zipped project --> http://sendfiles.org/sxl1H . Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks sir...i got it. i have to change framework to 4 from 4 client profile...lots of thanks.. :)

Comment: sir i have one doubt can we create Multi column treeview without using third party dll..because i tried with GTKSharp also..i succeded... :) but if i want to use only csharp..is thr any possible..

Comment: @user1283106: it's possible (ObjectListView dll is written in pure C# afterall) but is really complex, and it involves drawing all the components by hand... In brief, there's no TreeList in the basic C# library, so I think you should use a 3rd party dll.

Comment: @digEmAll i have a problem i try to implement this logic but not sucess can you please help me. i also post my question on below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689155/how-to-create-multiple-column-tree-view-design

Comment: So how can we modify node texts again using just the treeview?

Comment: Thanks a lot. +1 from me. this is great man.

Comment: How can i add icon to this list? please tell me.

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi : add an imageList (e.g. called imageList1) to your form (through toolbar->components) and add the desired images to it. Then set for example `this.treeListView.SmallImageList = imageList1;` and use `column.ImageGetter = (x) => nameOfTheImageInImageList;`

Comment: For further info : http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#on-the-rows-of-my-objectlistview-i-want-to-show-images-that-come-from-a-database-how-do-i-do-that

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks a lot my friend...

Answer (score -4):

http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html .. Download Gtksharp for ur operating system and add refrence of these dll in visual studio atk-sharp.dll , gdk-sharp.dll , glib-sharp.dll , gtk-sharp.dll and use  using Gtk; ... U will get the TreeView

```
 public class TreeViewExample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Gtk.Application.Init();
        new TreeViewExample();
        Gtk.Application.Run();
    }

    public TreeViewExample()
    {
        Gtk.Window window = new Gtk.Window("TreeView Example");
        window.SetSizeRequest(500, 200);

        Gtk.TreeView tree = new Gtk.TreeView();
        window.Add(tree);

        Gtk.TreeViewColumn Parent = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        Parent.Title = "Parent";
        Gtk.CellRendererText Parent1 = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        Parent.PackStart(Parent1, true);

        Gtk.TreeViewColumn ChildColoumn1 = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        ChildColoumn1.Title = "Column 1";           
        Gtk.CellRendererText Child1 = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        ChildColoumn1.PackStart(Child1, true);

        Gtk.TreeViewColumn ChildColumn2 = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
         ChildColumn2.Title = "Column 2";
        Gtk.CellRendererText Child2 = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        ChildColumn2.PackStart(Child2, true);

        tree.AppendColumn(Parent);
        tree.AppendColumn(ChildColoumn1);
        tree.AppendColumn(ChildColumn2);

        Parent.AddAttribute(Parent1, "text", 0);
        ChildColoumn1.AddAttribute(Child1, "text", 1);
        ChildColumn2.AddAttribute(Child2, "text", 2);

        Gtk.TreeStore Tree = new Gtk.TreeStore(typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string));
        Gtk.TreeIter iter = Tree.AppendValues("Parent1");
        Tree.AppendValues(iter, "Child1", "Node 1");

        iter = Tree.AppendValues("Parent2");
        Tree.AppendValues(iter, "Child1", "Node 1","Node 2");          

        tree.Model = Tree;
        window.ShowAll();
    }
}
```