# How do I handle a click event using the ObjectListView library?

Tags: c#, treelistview

I'm trying to use TreeListView, and i saw this post: [How to create a MultiColumn treeview like this in C# Winforms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802724/how-to-create-a-multicolumn-treeview-like-this-in-c-sharp-winforms-app).
But i don't understand how handle event when i click on tree node.
Could you help me?

i've tried to add event like this to form:

```
private void treeListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Debug.Print("HI");
}
```

but it doesn't works.

Thanks to @Robert Harvey answer, i added

treeListView.CellClick += treeListView_CellClick;
into FillTree method, where

```
private void treeListView_CellClick(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.CellClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("hi");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That post uses the [ObjectListView library](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).  If you download the source code for that library, open it in Visual Studio and examine Events.cs, you'll find this, in the partial class for TreeListView:

```
/// <summary>
/// This event is triggered when user input requests the expansion of a list item.
/// </summary>
[Category("ObjectListView"),
Description("This event is triggered when a branch is about to expand.")]
public event EventHandler<TreeBranchExpandingEventArgs> Expanding;

/// <summary>
/// This event is triggered when user input requests the collapse of a list item.
/// </summary>
[Category("ObjectListView"),
Description("This event is triggered when a branch is about to collapsed.")]
public event EventHandler<TreeBranchCollapsingEventArgs> Collapsing;

/// <summary>
/// This event is triggered after the expansion of a list item due to user input.
/// </summary>
[Category("ObjectListView"),
Description("This event is triggered when a branch has been expanded.")]
public event EventHandler<TreeBranchExpandedEventArgs> Expanded;

/// <summary>
/// This event is triggered after the collapse of a list item due to user input.
/// </summary>
[Category("ObjectListView"),
Description("This event is triggered when a branch has been collapsed.")]
public event EventHandler<TreeBranchCollapsedEventArgs> Collapsed;
```

There's also a bunch of events defined in that file for the `ObjectListView` class itself, including this one:

```
/// <summary>
/// Triggered when a cell is left clicked.
/// </summary>
[Category("ObjectListView"),
Description("This event is triggered when the user left clicks a cell.")]
public event EventHandler<CellClickEventArgs> CellClick;
```

Comment: ok, but if i add to form code objectListView's event like this:

private void treeListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("ciao");
        }

it doesnt work

Comment: Note that you can write event handlers all day long, but you still have to hook them up to get them to work.  Something like `MyTreeView.CellClick += new EventHandler(CellClick);`  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-create-event-handlers-at-run-time-for-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for more information about working with events.